# How to add wildcard for disable accounts with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I have the following PowerShell command which I run to show me all the numbers that have been assigned to users. However, I'd like to narrow it down to show me ONLY accounts which have been disabled BUT still have an number assigned, I've tried a few wildcards within 'enabled' but then it fails to run.

```
Get-ADUser -Properties "msRTCSIP-Line",mail,l,c,Enabled,CanonicalName -LDAPFilter "(msRTCSIP-Line=tel:+44*)" |
    Select Name,CanonicalName,mail,l,c,Enabled,"msRTCSIP-Line" |
    ft -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enabled/disabled status is encoded in the [`userAccountControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680832.aspx) attribute. Try an LDAP filter like this:

```
(&
    (objectclass=user)
    (objectcategory=user)
    (useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
    (msRTCSIP-Line=tel:*)
)
```

or collapsed:

```
(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=user)(useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(msRTCSIP-Line=tel:*))
```

Comment: I've managed to use the filter and was successful, many thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to get all disabled accounts then pipe it to your code :

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | %{
    Get-ADUser $_ -Properties "msRTCSIP-Line",mail,l,c,Enabled,CanonicalName -LDAPFilter "(msRTCSIP-Line=tel:+44*)" | 
    Select Name,CanonicalName,mail,l,c,Enabled,"msRTCSIP-Line"
}
```

Comment: It's more efficient to filter directly at the source (via the LDAP filter). Also, your code will show both enabled and disabled accounts.

Comment: nope...the search-adaccount will present only disabled users

Comment: *\*slaps self\** Sorry, for some reason I entirely failed to notice that part.